# How to add an action on a new button added on a backend form container

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, ajax, adminform, action

I've successfully added a new button on a form container (near New, Save, Save and Continue) in backend. I tried to use ajax... first adding JS code in adminhtml/layout/default. But the  js code I write does not recognize require or define statements, so I don't have access to requirejs/jquery. How can I properly include javascript in admin or how can I map a controller action to my custom button?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try:

Add javascript to content:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="protabs.script" template="Vendor_Module::script.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

You can change **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template** to your block

script.phtml (templates/script.phtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery'
], function(jQuery){
    (function($) {
        your script here...
    })(jQuery);
});
```